# Recover deleted files?

Tags: windows-10

My girlfriend had around 350 photos on her Camera from New Years. And I was going to transfer these to her computer (Windows 10).

So I transferred the files to two different locations on her computer, and then I deleted the files from the memory card.

Then I by accident clicked "undo move" = all the files gone from the computer not even in Recycle Bin. So I tried to do "redo" but this only took back the folders the photos where in, and not the photos.

I figured that this would be easy to recover since it was a undo, and not a delete. And also since the files where stored 3 times, 2 on the computer and 1 on the memory card.

So I tried to use the software "Recuva" but it couldn't restore anything.

Comment: If you have used file recovery without success then there isn't much else that can be done.

Comment: Did you use Recuva on the memory card?

Comment: TestDisk is a tool that I have had success with in the past. You can try using it on the memory card first, then the HD if that doesn't work. http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk

Comment: Thanks for all your help! With the software "Glary Undelete" I was able to restore 95% of the photos from the drive (Guess I was lucky since I tried to restore almost right away almost none of the files where overwritten)

How ever, I would still like to try to get the last 5% by trying to recover the memory card. How ever, none of the software I have tried let me choose the memory card as "search location", any advice?

Comment: Since you mention Recuva, this is from their home page: `Recuva can recover pictures, music, documents, videos, emails or any other file type you’ve lost. And it can recover from any rewriteable media you have: memory cards, external hard drives, USB sticks and more!`

Comment: Wierd, I can see the memory card under "This PC", but I cant see it from Recuva... :S